# Cross-compiling greenlet for linux arm target

Tags: python, arm

I want to build greenlet to use on arm32 linux box. I have an ubuntu machine, with my gcc cross-compiler for the arm target. How do I build greenlet for my target from my ubuntu machine?

Comment: I have done it for gentoo (you can customize my Makefile) and some qemu problems appear: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56302/qemu-2-7-0-for-the-raspi2-machine-do-not-show-the-second-tty-console-only-the . The better solution is to chroot to the arm root image and with qemu-binfmt to compile natively more architecture depended code.

Answer (score 0):

Build gevent with dependencies on QEMU raspberry pi.